# angular sortby not displaying results correctly

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I am trying to order my items based on the table's TH.

Example TH:

```
<th>ID&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('productID');">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
```

Example Row:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | filter:{manufacturer:by_manufac} | filter:byRange(priceInfo.min, priceInfo.max) | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit " ng-class="{'danger': data.errorStatus=='error'}">
```

Example Column:

```
<td ng-class='{red : data.Locked==1}'><center>{{data.productID}}</center></td>
```

The problem is that the result sort is weird. I have 586 rows with IDs ranges from 4 to 1059 (50 products per page).

startFrom filter:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
```

sort_by:

```
$scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
```

When i click the sorting icon, number 998 is listed first. when I click it again, 1000 is listed first. number 4, is never displayed first. Any Ideas why?

Thank you!

Comment: what does the `sort_by` function do?  it likely isn't taking into account the `startFrom` filter you have in place....

Comment: edit the question, don't add code in the comments.  comments aren't permanent, and they can't be formatted.

Comment: I think the productID attribute is not being parsed as INT.

Answer (score 0):

Please try angular-toArrayFilter, might solve your issue. http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It looks like the values (even though stored in the DB as INT, must be converted to int in order for the sorting to be done on numbers. Now it is working as it should.

In my case, I use PHP to get the items from the DB using `$http.get('ajax/getItems.php').success(function(data){...}`

In my PHP file:
I have added the row:

```
{
  $row["productID"] = intval($row["productID"]);
}
```

So now, the value of this row is forced to INT.

Comment: so did converting your values to INT actually solve your problem?  can you show how you made this change, so that others with the problem in the future might know what to do?

Comment: added explanation.